# Which stat determines how fast marksman rifle re-centers?

Tags: the-division

Which stat determines how fast a marksman rifle will re-center for follow-up shots? 
Which talents / mods would be best to increase that stat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stat you're looking for is [Accuracy](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/4ayt69/gun_stats_explained_stability_horizontal/). This controls the bullet spread, or the amount that your cursor will expand upon taking a shot.

There is a talent for this too, which is [Balanced](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/4a2yzd/balanced_weapon_talent/) which increases the speed at which you reach maximum accuracy when the weapons is shouldered. In essence this means that the cursor will narrow almost immediately, and is a fantastic talent for any Marksman rifle.

As for which things improve it, any mod with +Accuracy% will help here, which is usually optics and underbarrel mods.

Comment: What about _Initial Bullet Stability_? There are some people claiming that it's great for marksman rifles, others say it's _meh_.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that stat. The name suggests that it'll effect recoil on the first shot, making a follow-up shot easier, but I haven't ever used a mod with it on to test it in the Firing Range in the BoO.

Comment: @vartec Initial bullet stability determines how much spread you get on the crosshairs _after firing your first shot_

Comment: @Lumbejack: but for non-automatic weapons, what does count as "first" bullet?

Comment: Note that Balanced was intended to only apply when moving the weapon from your hip to your shoulder. There has been a bug from day one that applied this cone-reduction as long as the weapon was at your shoulder, but it will be fixed in the 1.2 patch.